# Select data from tables, if certain criteria is true then select max date for the records that are true

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using tableau 10.5 custom Sql pulling from an Oracle DB and would like to query off of the five tables in the picture. I have seen posts on here about pulling data based on max date if two values are the same but what I'm looking for is a little different. I want to select:

```
mnemonic,
problem_id,
create_date,
env_name
```

but when mnemonic, problem_id, and env_name are all the same I would like to only pull the record with the latest create_date.  In my actual scenario there are other values I want selected but I left those out of this post to simplify it.  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5ite.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help or points in the right direction!

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Hi,  Please edit the question and show sample data and expected output (as tables)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you want to select those columns:

- MNEMONIC from TABLE4
- PROBLEM_ID from TABLE3
- biggest CREATE_DATE from CREATE_DATE when other columns are the same
- ENV_NAME from TABLE2

Simply using [LEFT JOIN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52336) and [GROUP BY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) to get what you want:

```sql
SELECT TABLE4.MNEMONIC,
       TABLE3.PROBLEM_ID,
       MAX(TABLE1.CREATE_DATE) CREATE_DATE,
       TABLE2.ENV_NAME
  FROM TABLE1
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2
    ON (TABLE1.ENVIRONMENT_ID = TABLE2.ID)
  LEFT JOIN TABLE3
    ON (TABLE1.PROBLEM_ID = TABLE3.ID)
  LEFT JOIN TABLE4
    ON (TABLE1.MNEMONIC = TABLE4.ID)
 GROUP BY TABLE4.MNEMONIC,
          TABLE3.PROBLEM_ID,
          TABLE2.ENV_NAME;
```

P/s: You should review your table design. The column's name makes the viewer a little bit confuse. If I understand incorrect, then you got the idea to join and get information from multi tables.